# Displaying mysqli_fetch array results in dropdown php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a drop down that is being populated from a static select. Then when a choice is made in the first drop down a query runs and the second drop down is populated from the database depending on selection in first select box. Here is the code. I'm having a problem displaying the second drop down with the data.

```
$selectvalue = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['selectvalue']);

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT DISTINCT '$selectvalue' FROM accounts ");

echo '<option value="">Please select...</option>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<option value="'.$row['$selectvalue'].'">' . $row['$selectvalue'] . "</option>";
//echo $row['drink_type'] ."<br/>";
 }

 mysqli_free_result($result);
 mysqli_close($connection);

 ?>
```

Comment: `select distict 'foo'` is selecting the string `foo` from your table, you're not fetching a field. field/table names can NOT be quoted with `'`. you have to use backticks: ``select `foo` from``

Comment: is this the second select box? You are changing depending on first select box...don't you using ajax?

Comment: Yes, this is the second select box and I'm using ajax to send variable from first drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$selectvalue = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['selectvalue']);
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM accounts WHERE col_name = '".$selectvalue."' ");
echo '
<select name="some_name">
<option value="">Please select...</option>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['col_name'].'">'.$row['col_name']."</option>";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```